# The number of divisors of $0$ in a finite ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups

> Let $(A,+,•)$ be a ring with unity, which is not a division ring, and $|A|=25.$ Let $a$ be the number of divisors of $0$ in this ring. Then
>   a) $a=1;$
>   b) $a=2;$
>   c) $a=3;$
>   d) $a \geq 4.$

I guess that the answer is d), since this would be the case if we let $A=\mathbb{Z}/25 \mathbb{Z}.$ However, I couldn't prove it for general  $A.$

I know that a finite ring with $0 \neq 1$ which doesn't have divisors of $0$ is a division ring. Hence, our $A$ must have divisors of 0. I tried to use the characteristic and I got that it can only be $5$ or $25,$ but this is where I got stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $e\neq 0$ is a left zero divisor in $A$, then the set of zero divisors contains the left ideal $Ae$. Since this ideal is non-trivial (it contains $e$) and it is not equal to $A$ (it doesn't contain $1$) it is of size $5$. Thus you have at least $4$ zero divisors.

Comment: Great answer. I think it suffices to consider the additive subgroup generated by $e$ by the way. :)

Comment: Why would the ideal only have zero divisors? Consider the ring of 2x2 matrices over a field. The diagonal matrix $e$ with entries 1 and 0 is a zero divisor. But the ideal it generates is the whole ring because the matrix ring is simple.

Comment: True, there are no such matrix rings of 25 elements, but... you need to dig deeper to prove that. I will take @awllower's comment!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I considered the ring to be commutative, but you are right, I don't have this information. So we assume that $e$ is a left zero divisor and $\langle e\rangle$ is the left ideal. Thanks!

Comment: A nice fix. Sorry about jumping the gun a bit.